# Jquery toggle shows both divs briefly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have a working toggle that shows a div and then hides it, and then shows a second div in it's place on the click of a button. My issue is that once the button is clicked, they both show for a split second and I'd like to see if I can avoid that.

HTML and Jquery below

Working example here: http://jordanaharrison.com/Testing/Portfoliosite/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $div1 = $('#work'),
    $div2 = $('#play'),
    currentDiv = '',
    $button = $('button');

  $div2.hide();
  $button.text('' + currentDiv);

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(evt) {
    $div1.toggle('fade', 'fast');
    $div2.toggle('fade', 'fast');

    currentDiv = (currentDiv === '') ? '' : '';
    $button.text('' + currentDiv);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DualContain">
  <div class="SlideContain lightgreybg">
    <div id="work">
      <div id="desc">
        <div class="SectionHeader redbg">
          recent work
        </div>

        <div class="Headline red">
          Marketing Central
        </div>

        <div class="Subhead">
          Website Redesign
        </div>

        <div class="BodyCopy">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent blandit consectetur ex, ac commodo justo ultricies at. Nam iaculis egestas urna, sit amet tristique turpis.
        </div>
        <img height="20px" src="images/arrowred.png" width="20px">

        <div class="Clickthrough red">
          &nbsp;View More
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="image">
        <img src="images/Site2_04.png" width="100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="play">
      <div id="desc">
        <div class="SectionHeader greenbg" style="width:71px;">
          recent play
        </div>

        <div class="Headline green">
          First Dress Project
        </div>

        <div class="Subhead">
          Website Redesign
        </div>

        <div class="BodyCopy">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent blandit consectetur ex, ac commodo justo ultricies at. Nam iaculis egestas urna, sit amet tristique turpis.
        </div>
        <img height="20px" src="images/arrowgreen.png" width="20px">

        <div class="Clickthrough green">
          &nbsp;View More
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="image">
        <img src="images/Site2_04.png" width="100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="slidebtn">
    <img src="images/flip.png">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you want to show the second only after the first is done hiding?

Comment: @KJPrice - Yes, that is correct

Comment: @Taplar - Originally the button was text-based, but I changed it to an image and erased the text. I kept it in case I wanted to change it back.

Comment: Hide the one that's currently showing, and then show the new one in the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you need to have the first div's toggle function use a callback to the second div's toggle function.

```
$(selector).fadeToggle(speed,callback);
```

So your code might look something like this (edit to your document)

```
var first = $("#work");
var prev = $("#play");
var temp;
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(first).fadeToggle('slow', function() {
        $(prev).fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    temp = first;
    first = prev;
    prev = temp;
});
```

(You could use other, somewhat faster ways of getting the correct first div each time, but JQuery does not allow you to select div's with specific css attributes, such as hidden, without first selecting all divs and then looping, testing each one if it has the attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `$div2.hide();` and hide one of them within your css so that the html automatically hides one, then you start your toggle cycle.